# rollback received jms messages

Tags: jakarta-ee, transactions, jms, rollback

How can I receive multiple messages of a queue in Transaction and at some point rollback so that other programs which consumes messages from this queue can receive the messages?

im trying to do it somehow like this:

```
ObjectMessage obj = (objectMessage) consumer.receive();

ObjectMessage obj2 = (ObjectMessage) consumer.receive(10000);
if(obj2 == null) session.rollback(); //if we haven't received thesecond message after 10     second, also the first message should be rolled back so other consumerprograms can take it.
```

Answer (score 2):

some point rollback so that other programs which consumes messages from this queue can receive the messages?

Roll back is not good strategy to send message back to queue and others consume it. If you want to propagate message to multiple consumers then use Tpoic instead of the Queue.

About sending back message.
Rollback/ re-sending messages to JMS broker depends on the acknowledgement mode.

If you acknowledgement is transaction based then use

```
session.rollback();
```

other wise use following

```
session.recover();
```

It will revert back all the unacknowledged messages back to the JMS broker.

Other than AUTO acknowledge mode message stays with broker until you acknowledge or commit your session based on acknowledge setting.

So when you are done with the successful message processing acknowledge it. If msg processing has error/exception then rollback/recover to send back. If you don't want to process failed messages(let it be time constraint processing/not processed in given time) again then just acknowledge message and log the error. There is no restriction on sending message in between.

Rolledback messages may again come back to same client again so not rollback may not be useful completely unless you use selectors. Check selectors it allows you to do content based routing.

Comment: hello, and thank you. I don't want to propagate the message to all the consumers. The "Server" sends a messages to the queue. Programm a consumes those messages and if it waits more than 10 seconds for a new message it should write back the received messages so other consumers could have it. Isn't rollback the right way to go?

Comment: the messages are like Component of a car (engine, tire and chassis). clients consumes the messages and build a car with them. now say a client already has received (in an uncommitted transaction session) anengine, chassis and 3 tires) but there is no new Tire message arriving... in this case i want the client to write back all its components (the 3 tires, engine and chassis) to the queue, so that another client, which waits for say a chassis can have it to complete its car. so i don't want to write back on a failure but on a timeout (if after 30 seconds no new component arrives ,write back)

Comment: Try JMS selector and enable content based routing because rolledback message may again come back to same client.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear to me why program a wants to rollback. Is it not capable of processing the received message? why other consumers would need the same message?

You can also use the `clientAcknowledge` message acknowledge mode for 'write back' of the received message. In this mode, you don't do a `message.acknowledge()` for the received message.

Comment: `javax.jms.Message.acknowledge()` is a little bit misleading because by invoking `acknowledge` on a single message client acknowledges  *all* messages consumed by the session that the message was delivered - one cannot acknowledge only selected message.

Comment: True. However some JMS clients provide per message acknowledge feature. I think ActiveMQ does it